# How can i error out an entry if it already exists?

Tags: input, count, vi

I'm writing a simple program to add a contact into a file called "phonebook", but if the contact already exists, i want it to return an echo saying " (first name last name) already exists", and not add it to the file. So far, i've gotten the program to add the user, but it wont return that echo and adds the duplicate entry anyway. How can i fix this?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Check that 5 arguments are passed
    #

    if [ "$#" -ne 5 ]
    then
          echo
          echo "Usage: first_name last_name phone_no room_no building"
          echo
          exit 1
    fi

    first=$1
    last=$2
    phone=$3
    room=$4
    building=$5

    # Count the number of times the input name is in add_phonebook

    count=$( grep -i "^$last:$first:" add_phonebook | wc -l )

    #echo $count

    # Check that the name is in the phonebook

    if [ "$count" -eq 1 ]
       then
          echo
          echo "$first $last is already in the phonebook."
          echo
          exit 1
    fi

    # Add someone to the phone book
    #

    echo "$1        $2      $3      $4      $5" >> add_phonebook

    # Exit Successfully

    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

Should check if add_phonebook file exists before attempting to grep it, otherwise you get the `grep: add_phonebook: No such file or directory` output.

Your grep expression doesn't match the format of the file.

You are saving the file with space in between the fields, but searching with a colon(:) between the names. You can either update the file format to use a colon to separate the fields, or update the grep expression to search on space. In addition, you save first name, last_name, but search on last_name, first_name.

With space format:

```
count=$( grep -i "^$last[[:space:]]\+$first[[:space:]]" add_phonebook | wc -l )
```

Comment: I noticed that grep was using a colon delimiter so i replaced it with a tab (as that as what im using in the last echo field), and yes i made sure the add_phonebook file existed before trying to add input, but still no luck

Comment: The off thing i notice, is when use the command `count=$( grep -i "^$last        $first  " add_phonebook | wc -l )` and then display the count, it shows as 0, which it should be displaying as 1 since i know the $last and $first are already in the "add_phonebook" file. When i use that same count command outside of VI, it counts accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Removed my tab separators from the echo line, used spaces, and now it can count properly